# Rails 5.1.: Jbuilder format single JSON object in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, jbuilder

I have this piece of code in my `update.json.jbuilder`

```
json.data do
  json.(@user_group, :id, :name, :description)
  json.users @user_group.users, :id, :name
  json.roles @user_group.roles, :id, :name
end
```

which gives me this JSON:

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":95,
      "name":"Management group",
      "description":"This is management group",
      "users":[
         {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Test User"
         }
      ],
      "roles":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"FULL ACCESS (TEMPORARY)"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**How do I wrap "data" in array to something like this, please?**

```
{
   "data": [ 
    {
      "id":95,
      "name":"Management group",
      "description":"This is management group",
      "users":[
         {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Test User"
         }
      ],
      "roles":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"FULL ACCESS (TEMPORARY)"
         }
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Notice [ ] after first and last { }
So far I've been trying to implement `json.array!`, but no luck as it throws me `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method map` which means I'm trying to put together something which probably does not fit [as mentioned here](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/239).

Answer (score 1):

With [child! method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder:child!) it seems to be this simple:

```
json.data do
  json.child! do
    json.(@user_group, :id, :name, :description)
    json.users @user_group.users, :id, :name
    json.roles @user_group.roles, :id, :name
  end
end
```